# JasperReports CompileReport

Tags: glassfish, jasper-reports

I'm writing a sample application to create a report using JasperReports. As a desktop java app [jar] I'm able to take an template and convert it into a report without an issue. However [with the same libraries set] I'm not able to do this under Glassfish [as an servlet].

I'm getting lots of errors when the report is being compiled.

```
String jrFile = "/WEB-INF/HelloWorld.jrxml";
InputStream irs = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(jrFile);
JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(irs);
```

Many of the errors reported are:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:

package net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill does not exist
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.*;
```

Under the exception:

```
61 errors

    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:191)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:215)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:201)
```

Comment: I solved the problem for WebLogic 10.0, JasperReports 6.0.0 by using jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar from 28/12/2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I lacked the JDT-*.jar in my classpath. Once that was added, then the errors went away.

Comment: I have the same problem. Can you tell me where you got the JDT jar?

Answer (score 4):

yes it was very useful you can download jdt-compiler3.1.1.jar file from following link http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/jasperreports/JasperReports%203.5.3/jasperreports-3.5.3-project.zip/download

you need to download jasperreports-3.5.3-project.zip file and take jdt-compiler3.1.1.jar from lib folder and add it to your project it will start working.