# Report fails on glassfish

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, glassfish, jasper-reports

I've made a report using iReport 5.1.0 and deployed on Tomcat server and it works just fine. But when is deployed in production server (Glassfish 3.1), the report never shows up.
The glassfish log is empty, so no error was found.

When i run in eclipse (debug mode at Glassfish), the execution seems to jump in

```
JasperViewer jasperViewer = new JasperViewer(re, false, null);
```

line.

Next to this message is the code i've been using, and working, in Tomcat.

P.D. Forgive my english i'm a native spanish speaker.

The code:

```
public boolean mostrarReporte(String template, Map parametros) {
        JasperReport report = null;
        JasperPrint re = null;
        Connection conn = conexion();
        boolean success = true;

        try {
            String in = FacesUtils.getExternalContext().getRealPath(
                    "/reportTemplates/" + template);
            report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(in);

            re = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parametros, conn);
            JasperViewer jasperViewer = new JasperViewer(re, false, null);
            // Mostrar el reporte
            jasperViewer.setVisible(true);
            jasperViewer.setDefaultCloseOperation(0);
            parametros.clear();

        } catch (JRException e) {
            success = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return success;
    }
```

Comment: Probably a dependency conflict. Check this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587328/jasperreports-compilereport

Comment: @chalo1970 Is it a code of an *Java* applet?

Comment: @AlexK, no its'nt, is a code of a web application.

Comment: @chalo1970 Do you really want to show report on the server side with help of *JasperViewer*?

Comment: @AlexK I don't understand, JasperViewer shows the report on server side? If so, what can i do to show report on client side? Is a web application and that's what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have all jasper libraries on your production server : they should be under glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext. If the jars are not there (or some of them - like the fonts or some other not mandatory lib), you might experience the behavior you are describing. Also make sure that the database on the production machine is not empty. If there is no data to display, jasper shows an empty page.

Comment: The database is not empty, in fact i've already test the code in develop computer with Glassfish and the behavior is the same as production server. Also all the libraries included at jasperreports are in WEB-INF/lib folder. Any idea?